# Using hashed columns of SQL Server database in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, encryption

I'm trying to make a website using asp.net mvc 4 & Entity Framework 6 & the database is SQL Server 2012. I have a column in `UserPassword` table where all the passwords are encrypted like this, `D1-24-0F-FB-16-AA-A9-CB-50-22-18-8D-E4-AF-59-CA`. I want to use these datas for login in the website. I've tried but not working.

This is my code:

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    abncodbEntities db = new abncodbEntities();

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(UserPassword id)
    {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var uservar = db.UserPasswords.Where(a => a.UserId.Equals(id.UserId) && a.Password.Equals(id.Password)).FirstOrDefault();

            if (uservar != null)
            {
                Session["UserBOID"] = uservar.UserId.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("UserLogin");
            }
        }

        return View(id);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model ABCoLtd.Models.UserPassword
using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="editor-label">
            <strong>Enter your ID</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.UserId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.UserId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <strong>Password</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)
        </div><br />
        <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Login" /></p>
    }
```

If I only try with ID then it works but not working with password. How can I use the passwords for login? I'm new in this situation. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't need it to be in plain text. I just want to make it usable in my asp.net mvc 4 project. Is there any way?

Comment: What ever algorithm is used to hash the original password when its first added needs to be run again for the login password and then compared

Comment: As @StephenMuecke mentioned, you must encrypt that password with the same algorithm and compare it with encrypted passwords.